# $scope.$apply equivalent in Angular5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm working on a project (Ionic3 and Angular5).

I've changed the value in the following input from an external .js file

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name" 
       (ngModelChange)="valueChange()" 
       id="data">
```

But function `valueChange()` is not be called.

I've done that before in *Angular1* using `$scope.$apply`, but in *Angular5* I don't know how to do the same thing. What's the equivalent way of doing this in *Angular5*?

Answer (score 0):

`markForCheck()`: Marks all ChangeDetectionStrategy ancestors as to be checked.
`detectChanges()`: Checks the change detector and its children.

Example:-

```
import { Component,
         Input,
         ChangeDetectionStrategy,
         ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() data: string[];

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  refresh() {
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

This is very nice article about Angular change detection:- https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/